# How to rebuild a Fedora package with a different compiler?

Tags: fedora, american-fuzzy-lop

Similarly to [this question ("How can I automatically rebuild a package with a different compiler?" on askubuntu.com)](https://askubuntu.com/q/667381/103933), I would like to know how can I automate fetching source and compilation of a C program using Fedora build scripts using a specific, non-default compiler - in my case `afl-gcc`. I would definitely welcome an example of the `pv` program, but I would like the solution to work for other packages, like `libreoffice` as well, with minimal modifications. I would like to achieve something similar to [aflize](https://github.com/d33tah/aflize) (which is for Debian only right now). I have heard of [mock](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Mock?rd=Subprojects/Mock) and it would be best if I could use it for that.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know to do it automatically, but manually:

- Prepare build environnement

  $ rpmdev-setuptree
- Download corresonding srpms

  $ yumdownloader --source foo
- Extract files from SRPMS

  $ rpm -i foo*.src.rpm
- Replace the compiler used

  $ sed -i 's/make all/make CC=afl-gcc all/g' ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/foo.spec

setting `CC` var your corresponding compiler will do the jobs.

If you use `cmake` take a look to `CMAKE_C_COMPILER`

- Rebuild

  $ cd ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/

  $ rpmbuild -ba foo.spec

Generated rpm files are located into `~/rpmbuild/RPMS`